# Spring Batch JdbcPagingItemReader sort by two columns/keys

Tags: spring-batch

I have this JdbcPagingItem reader and I want to sort by 2 columns.

```
Map<String, Order> sortKey = new HashMap<>();
sortKey.put("xbin", Order.ASCENDING);
sortKey.put("ybin", Order.ASCENDING);
```

Since the sortKey is a Map, I think this should work.

I need some confirmation if this is how I am supposed to do?

thx, Markus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can sort items by multiple columns and your code snippet is correct. The resulting query performed by the item reader will be something like:

```
select ... from table .. ORDER BY xbin ASC, ybin ASC
```